# C++, свойста шаблонов, работа с памятью

Tags: c++, память, шаблоны-с++, sizeof

```c
template <typename type>
bool is_array(type const &var) {
    std::cout << sizeof(var) << " " << sizeof(type);
    return sizeof(var) > sizeof(type);
}

int main() {
    int a[10], b;
    is_array(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему вышеуказанный код показывает, что

```c
sizeof(var) == sizeof(type) == 40
```

как я могу получить тип переменного? Чтоб получилось так

```c
sizeof(var) == 40 
sizeof(type) == 4
```

Comment: Тип переменной уже известен - это `int ( & )[10]`. `sizeof(var) == sizeof(type) == 40` потому что `sizeof` примененный к ссылке возвращает размер типа, на который ссылается ссылка.

Comment: Если вы хотите свой `std::is_array`, то он работает не так.

Answer (score 0):

"Вышеуказанный код" показывает, что `sizeof(var) == sizeof(type)` потому, что это так и есть. Это скорее у вас нужно спрашивать, почему вы ожидали иного результата.

Если тип `T` - массив, то тип элемента этого массива вы можете получить через `std::remove_extent<T>::type` или `std::remove_all_extents<T>::type`, в зависимости от того, что именно вам нужно

```
template <typename type>
bool is_array(type const &var) 
{
    using element = typename std::remove_all_extents<type>::type;
    std::cout << sizeof(type) << " " << sizeof(element) << std::endl;
    return sizeof(type) > sizeof(element);
}

int main() 
{
    int a[10];
    is_array(a);
}
```

Comment: Как мы можем здесь использовать слово `using` ? Разве это не для пространств имен? И какая функция оно здесь выполняет? Спасибо)

Comment: @Հայկ Ավետիսյան : Начиная с C++11 слово `using` имеет новые замечательные применения. В данном случае это аналог `typedef`. Можете использовать классический `typedef` вместо `using`, подправив соответствующим образом синтаксис.